# Returning BinaryFileResponse to Custom Block

Tags: blocks

Alright, so I have a custom block that is implements a build() method. I also have a controller which loads in terms and should they pass certain requirements, it will return a binary file response, displaying an SVG file. I want my custom block to call this controller method and display the rendered BinaryFileResponse, but I'm not quite sure how to do this.

My block code is as follows

```
class MapplicBlock extends BlockBase {

/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function build() {
  $svgFile = new MapplicSvgController;
  $mapSvg = $svgFile->_mapplic_svg();

  return [    
    '#markup' => $mapSvg,
    '#attached' => array(
      'library' => array(
        'mapplic/mapplic',
       ),
     ),
   ];
  }
}
```

where my controller is MapplicScgController and _mapplic_svg() is the svg serving method in the controller.

The function _mapplic_svg() ends up handing back

```
return new BinaryFileResponse($uri, 200, $headers);
```

It works just fine. Output is the SVG image in browser, but in my block it comes out as:

HTTP/1.0 200 OK 0: Content-Type Cache-Control: public Date: Fri, 13 Jul 2018 17:01:11 GMT Last-Modified: Wed, 11 Jul 2018 19:08:26 GMT 1: text/csv; utf-8"

How do I get the block to display the rendered SVG instead of this meat-data related to it?

Picture of _mapplic_svg() output.

[image]

Comment: When you say _Output is the SVG image in browser_, how does that happen exactly? Do you mean that you have a route returning the SVG binary, and when you visit that route separately it works? I'm not sure the approach you're using would end up working, but if it would, you'll need to get the contents out of the response (you're currently rendering the response object, which outputs the headers). That would be something like `$mapSvg = $svgFile->_mapplic_svg()->getBody()->getContents();`

Comment: @Clive I'll post a image of what it's outputting. That makes sense though.